Show that ${}_2F_1[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} + x, 1 + x, e^{-2 / x}] = \Theta(\sqrt{x})$ at $x \to \infty$
I want to show that ${}_2F_1[\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2} + x; 1 + x; e^{-2 / x}] = \Theta(\sqrt{x})$. This appears to be true numerically. In fact, the multiplicative constant seems to approach ~.645 as $x \to \infty$.
The typical functional identities for hypergeometric functions don't really help much here (e.g. from DLMF). I also checked this paper though it appears the results only apply for fixed $z$, where here z is a function of $x$.
Bonus points to generalize this and show that ${}_2F_1[\beta; \beta + x; 1 + x; e^{-2 / x}] = \Theta(x^\beta)$ for $\beta > 0$, which also appears to be true.
Edit: the expansion in eq 2.5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0205065 seems relevant.
$$
\begin{align*}
{}_2F_1[a; \beta + \lambda; \gamma +\lambda; z] &= (1-z)^{-a} {}_2F_1[a; c-b; c; \frac{z}{z-1}]
\\&=(1-z)^{-a}\left(1 + \frac{a(\gamma - \beta)}{\gamma + \lambda} \frac{z}{z-1} + \cdots\right)
\end{align*}
$$
This uses the standard series representation
$$
{}_2F_1[a; b;c;z]=\sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_s (b)_s}{(c)_s s!}z^s
$$
The paper goes on to show an asymptotic with a fixed $z$, but I will try to see if I can get an expression with our values.

Using the integral representation of $2F1(a,b;c;z)$ for
$c>b$ https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/
$$2F1 \Big(\frac12,\frac12+x;1+x;e^{-\frac 2x}\Big)=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma\big(\frac12+x\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)}\int_0^1t^{x-\frac12}(1-t)^{-\frac12}(1-te^{-\frac2x})^{-\frac12}dt$$
$$\sim\frac1{B\big(\frac12;\frac12+x\big)}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t+\frac2x}}\sim\sqrt{\frac x\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}dt\approx0.645694,\sqrt x$$

@Svyatoslav thank you very much. Apologies but would you please mind explaining how you arrived at the last two expressions? Everything outside of the integral is clear (the beta identity, and the beta asymptotic).

It can be done in rigorous way, but heuristically, at $x\to\infty$
$$\int_0^1t^{x-\frac12}(1-t)^{-\frac12}(1-te^{-\frac2x})^{-\frac12}dt=\int_0^1(1-t)^{x-\frac12}t^{-\frac12}(1-(1-t)e^{-\frac2x})^{-\frac12}dt$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{e^{x\ln(1-t)}}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}\Big((1-e^{-\frac2x})+te^{-\frac2x}\Big)^{-\frac12}dt\approx\int_0^1\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t}}\Big(\frac2x+t\Big)^{-\frac12}dt$$
$$\overset{xt=s}{=}\int_0^x\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt{s(2+s)}}ds\overset{s=t^2}{=}\int_{-\sqrt x}^{\sqrt x}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}ds$$

In the second line only $t$ near zero contributes (some smaller factors are dropped)

Thank you very much. Every step is clear now (though I may need to think harder about rigorously showing the heuristic step). Would you like to post it as an official answer so I can accept it?

@csharrison Did any of us answer your question?

Yes I believe  the answer from @Svyatoslav is the most complete, but I need to check the steps before accepting. Please give me some time to check the work.

Using $(15.8.1)$, $(14.3.9)$ and $(14.15.2)$, we find that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt x}{}_2F_1\! \left( \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2} + x;1 + x;{\rm e}^{ - 2/x}  \right) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt {x(1 - {\rm e}^{ - 2/x} )} }{}_2F_1\!  \left( \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1 + x;\tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{1}{2}\coth \left( \tfrac{1}{x} \right) \right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt {x(1 - {\rm e}^{ - 2/x} )} }{\rm e}\,\Gamma (1 + x)P_{ - 1/2}^{ - x} \left( \coth \left( \tfrac{1}{x} \right) \right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt {x(1 - {\rm e}^{ - 2/x} )} }{\rm e}\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }} K_0 (1)\!\left( 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right) \\ & = \sqrt {\frac{-2/x}{{\rm e}^{ - 2/x}-1 }} \frac{\rm e}{\sqrt \pi }K_0 (1)\!\left( 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)
\end{align*}
as $x\to+\infty$. Thus,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}{}_2F_1\! \left( \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2} + x;1 + x;{\rm e}^{ - 2/x}  \right) =\frac{\rm e}{\sqrt \pi }K_0 (1)=0.64569414838203\ldots\;.
$$

To the nice solution by @Gary we can add the consideration of the general case and prove that
$$_2F_1\Big(\beta, \beta+x;1+x;e^{-\frac2x}\Big)\sim\frac e{\sqrt\pi}2^{\frac12-\beta}K_{\frac12-\beta}(1)\,x^\beta;\,\,\beta\in[0;1];\,\,x\to\infty\tag{1}$$
where $\displaystyle K_n (s)$ is the modified Bessel's function of the second kind:
$$K_n(s)=\frac{\sqrt\pi\big(\frac s2\big)^n}{\Gamma\big(n+\frac12\big)}\int_0^\infty e^{-s\cosh t}\sinh^{2n}(t)dt\tag{2}$$
Using the integral representation of $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$
$\displaystyle_2F_1\Big(\beta, \beta+x;1+x;e^{-\frac2x}\Big)=$
$$=\frac1{B(1-\beta;\beta+x)}\int_0^1e^{x\ln(1-t)}(1-t)^{\beta-1}t^{-\beta}\Big(1-e^{-\frac2x}-te^{-\frac2x}\Big)^{-\beta}dt$$
$$\overset{\ln(1-t)=-s}{=}\frac1{B(1-\beta;\beta+x)}\int_0^1e^{-sx}e^{-s(\beta-1)}(1-e^{-s})^{-\beta}\Big(1-e^{-\frac2x-s}\Big)^{-\beta}e^{-s}ds$$
$$\overset{sx=t}{=}\frac1{x\,B(1-\beta;\beta+x)}\int_0^xe^{-t}e^{-\frac tx\beta}\Big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\Big)^{-\beta}\Big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\Big)^{-\beta}dt$$
It is straightforward to get
$$\frac1{B(1-\beta;\beta+x)}\sim\frac{x^{1-\beta}}{\Gamma(1-\beta)}\,\,\text{at}\,\,x\to \infty$$
now we want to find
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-2\beta}\int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}e^{-\frac{\beta t}x}}{\big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\big)^\beta\big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\big)^\beta}dt$$
We notice that on the interval $t\in[0;x]$
$$\frac tx\leqslant4\Big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\Big)\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\frac1 {x^\beta}\frac1{\big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\big)^\beta}\leqslant\Big(\frac4t\Big)^\beta$$
and also for $x\geqslant 1$
$$4\Big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\Big)>\frac {t+2}x\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\frac1 {x^\beta}\frac1{\big(1-e^{-\frac {2+t}x}\big)^\beta}<\Big(\frac4{t+2}\Big)^\beta$$
It means that the function
$$f(t,x)=\frac1{x^{2\beta}}\frac{e^{-t}e^{-\frac{\beta t}x}}{\big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\big)^\beta\big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\big)^\beta}\,\chi_{[0;x]}\,\,(\text{i.e.}\,\,f(t,x)=0\,\,\text{at}\,\,t>x)$$
is majorized on the interval $t\in[0;\infty)$ by the integrable function
$$f(t,x)< g(t)=e^{-t}\Big(\frac4t\Big)^{\beta}\Big(\frac4{t+2}\Big)^{\beta}$$
According to the dominated convergence theorem we are allowed to take the limit $x\to\infty$ under the integral sign
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^{2\beta}}\frac{e^{-t}e^{-\frac{\beta t}x}}{\big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\big)^\beta\big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\big)^\beta}\,\chi_{[0;x]}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{x^{2\beta}}\frac{e^{-t}e^{-\frac{\beta t}x}}{\big(1-e^{-\frac tx}\big)^\beta\big(1-e^{-\frac{2+t}x}\big)^\beta}\,\chi_{[0;x]}\right)dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\big(t(2+t)\big)^\beta}dt$$
and find that
$$_2F_1\Big(\beta, \beta+x;1+x;e^{-\frac2x}\Big)\sim\frac{x^{1-\beta}}{\Gamma(1-\beta)}\frac1xx^{2\beta}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\big(t(2+t)\big)^\beta}dt$$
$$=\frac{x^\beta}{\Gamma(1-\beta)}\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{1-s}}{(s^2-1)^\beta}ds\overset{s=\cosh t}{=}\frac {e\,x^\beta}{\Gamma(1-\beta)}\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh t}\sinh^{1-2\beta}(t)\,dt$$
Using (2), we find that $\,n=\frac12-\beta\,,\,\,s=1\,$, and get the asymptotics (1)

$${}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2} + x; 1 + x; e^{-2 / x}\right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(\frac12+x\right)_n}{\left(1+x\right)_n}\frac{(e^{-\frac2x})^n}{n!}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n}{n!}(e^{-\frac2x})^nO(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{-\frac12\choose n}(-e^{-\frac2x})^nO(1)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac2x}}}O(1)=O(\sqrt x)$$
since $\frac{\left(\frac12+x\right)_n}{\left(1+x\right)_n}=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n}{n!}=(-1)^n{-\frac12\choose n}$.

Your final result contradicts mine. How do we resolve this?

@Gary I don't think it is a contradiction.  Maybe, $\frac{\left(\frac12+x\right)_n}{\left(1+x\right)_n}\sim 1$ as $x\to\infty$ is a bad approximation.

Well, we got to different asymptotic constants. At most one of them can be correct.

@Gary I dont see another idea to find that asymptotic constant with this approach.
